# Default value for multiple select question

Tags: commcare

Is there a way to pre populate a Checkbox question using a Default Value? For example, if I had a question like:

What are your favorite fruits?

- Apple
- Banana
- Orange

And I wanted Apple (or Apple and Banana) by default to be checked, can I do that with the Default Value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one of two ways, both of which involve providing an entry in the Default Value section of the form builder.

1. You can hard code a space separated list between single quotes

   - `'apple orange'`
2. You can use the `join` or `concat` functions to build that list dynamically in a way that generates a space separated list of values

   - `join(' ', /data/path/to/repeat)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  Just put "apple" (or whatever the option id is for Apple) into the default field for the question.

Comment: Great, if I wanted more than one checked?

Comment: You can't have more than one checked for a multiple choice question (those only allow 1 answer).  But if you want more than one checked for a Checkbox question, you can put in a default which is a space-sparated list of the option ids.  Example: "apple orange"

Comment: Great, sorry I meant Checkbox question when I said multiple choice, sorry. Updated question